# Wilderness Regrowth with Towny

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

Is it possible to use the [Towny](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-fun-info-chat-tp-towny-advanced-v0-78-0-0-land-control-and-town-management-1597.25101/) plugin for Bukkit for Minecraft to regrow "wilderness" areas?

I'm hoping to allow blocks that are commonly harvested, like sand, to regrow over time so the landscape isn't destroyed by people harvesting sand for glass (as an example). I know you can do this with creeper explosions, so if there is a way to do this for player destruction then please let me know.

Comment: +1, that would be great. I always hate seeing the landscape destroyed. I'm a Minecraft environmentalist :D

Comment: If this doesn't exist then I would be interested in taking a look at the code and see if the current creeper regrowth can't be adapted for this use too.

Comment: I've never heard of this creeper regrowth before, but I'm sure it would be. Just change it so it reacts to *all* damage, instead of just creeper damage.

Comment: You could make mining in the nice areas impossible (I don't know if Towny supports this, if not try [WorldGuard](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard)) and instead offer quarries or shops selling blocks. I remember there is also a plugin (the name of which I forgot) that allows to undo the actions of individual players, which could probably be modified to suit your needs

Comment: appendix: The plugin I meant is [BigBrother](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/unsupported-sec-bigbrother-1-11-0-catch-griffers-red-handed-1060.12879/) (good thing I bookmark everything...) but unfortunately it seems to have gone stale

Comment: I use hawkeye for player monitoring and rollbacks, but it wouldn't be feasible to regularly rollback areas to restore landscape, as it would likely have unintended side effects (hidden tunnels being destroyed, etc). I used to use BB, but as you said, it's stale. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this has already been [suggested and shot down](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/towny/issues/detail?id=522) a month ago, so the short answer is no.  Interesting feasibility analysis there in the response, though the issues seem possible to overcome...

The [source is available though](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/towny/source/checkout) if you want to take a crack at it.

Comment: Looks like they took the easy way out of solving the problem considering that they could (and should) simply monitor player triggered events... oh well.

Comment: Though to be fair, it only looks like one person is interested in the change judging by the issue and they currently have 55 open enhancement requests.  Gotta expect them to take 'the easy way' most of the time.  Oh well, at least it's open source...